# ASP.NET MVC2 DateTime Control

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, templates

i am looking for a date time control/template for mvc2 anybody of you know a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that.

I would suggest you to use a JavaScript Framework to do that:

The most popular ones are the [jQuery-Ui DatePicker](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-ui-datepicker) and the [Telerik MVC DatePicker](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/datepicker.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the datepicker in the jQuery UI library. http://jqueryui.com/